# Using additional library

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to use a custom calendar. (show it through xml-markup). But the app crash. What could be the reason? All I have done as it is written here. Made by Gradle manually inserting build.gradle. I have the same problem with other similar libraries, have already tried to use 5-6 libraries.
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.denis.myplans.NewNoteActivity">

<com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

from error log:

```
  03-28 21:30:36.222 7338-7338/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.denis.myplans, PID: 7338
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.denis.myplans/com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                     at com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                     at com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; regionStart=0; regionLength=3
                                                     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
                                                     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
                                                     at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.initializeWeekLayout(CustomCalendarView.java:171)
                                                     at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.refreshCalendar(CustomCalendarView.java:356)
                                                     at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.initializeCalendar(CustomCalendarView.java:132)
                                                     at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.<init>(CustomCalendarView.java:74)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                     at com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.denis.myplans"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0'
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.denis.myplans;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final Intent intNewNote = new Intent(this, NewNoteActivity.class);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        assert fab != null;

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(intNewNote);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36268263/edit) to include the full error message.

Comment: There is still much code you are missing here... Like your MainActivity and the build.gradle, but have you [read the documentation](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/blob/master/README.md) for how to use this calendar view?

Comment: share your build.gradle file please.  I think there is an issue there

Comment: Yes I do... and did everything as it is written there

Comment: Add your activity, particularly line 19. Your app is crashing due to an index out of bounds. Look at this part of your stacktrace: "Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; regionStart=0; regionLength=3" and it seems to be related to how you're initializing the weeks

Comment: I think that the problem is to connect library ... because it does not display even just layout

Answer (score 0):

For use this library you need read how can implement, first need add on your build.gradle the Jitpack repository.

After

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

you should add this

```
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

On your Maven repository and dependency needs look like this.

```
<repository>
 <id>jitpack.io</id>
 <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.npanigrahy</groupId>
 <artifactId>Custom-Calendar-View</artifactId>
 <version>v1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After that it should Works.